# Probabilistic calulation of the Fourier transform of the Cantor function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

This is on the same theme as in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220431/14108), where the Fourier transform was derived using simple function.

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the Cantor function.
Then $f$ is the cumulative distribution of a Cantor distributed random variable
$$
X=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} Y_n
$$
where the $Y_n$ are i.i.d. and takes values $0$ and $2$ with equal probability.

In this MO [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44979/evil-fourier-coefficients/44999#44999), it is stated that
$$
E(e^{itY_n})=e^{it/2}\cos(3^{-n} t).
$$

How do we get that? I have
$$
E(e^{itY_n})=\frac{e^{it2/3^n}+1}{2}.
$$

Also, it is stated in the post that 
$$
\hat f(t)=\frac{1}{it} -\frac{1}{it}\hat {f'}(t).
$$

How do we get this one? I thought
$$
\hat f(t)=\frac{1}{it}\hat {f'}(t)
$$
only.

Comment: It makes sense to link to [closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220431) questions that you asked before, since it provides more context and may allow people to build on what's already been done.

Comment: @joriki I though this was done automatically somehow. Thanks for notifying me that I should do it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
E[e^{itX}]&=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}E[e^{it3^{-n}Y_n}]\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{it2\cdot 3^{-n}}+1}2\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{it \cdot 3^{-n}}\cos(t3^{—n})\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{it \cdot 3^{-n}}\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos(t3^{-n})\\
&=\exp\left(it\sum_{n\geq 1}3^{—n}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos(t3^{-n})\\
&=\exp(it/2)\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos(t3^{-n}).
\end{align}